# insert xsi:schemaLocation and xlmns and prefix in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I am trying to insert xsi and xsmln data into XML, I have used various ways but I could not get it, I also need to insert prefixes. Next I show my code where I get the XML and I also show you the structure I get, and at the end I show you what I really want to get.
This is the code where I get the XML:

```
string txtXML = XmlfrommyfunctionSQL();    // here retrieve from sqlserver          
            XDocument doc;
            using (StringReader s = new StringReader(txtXML))
            {
                doc = XDocument.Load(s);
            }
            doc.Declaration = new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
            string targetxml = doc.ToString();
            targetxml = doc.Declaration.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + doc.ToString();
```

This is the XML I get in string targetxml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice>
    <UBLxtensions>
        <UBLExtension>
            <AccountingSupplierParty>
                <AdditionalAccountID>1</AdditionalAccountID>
                <Party>
                    <PartyName>
                        <Name>GRUPO ERB</Name>
                    </PartyName>
                    <PhysicalLocation>
                        <Address>
                            <ID>11001</ID>
                            <Country>
                                <IdentificationCode>CO</IdentificationCode>
                            </Country>
                        </Address>
                    </PhysicalLocation>
                </Party>
            </AccountingSupplierParty>
        </UBLExtension>
    </UBLExtensions>
</Invoice>
```

But I need to insert xsi:schemaLocation and xmlns, and insert prefix in Elemnts, how do I do that ?
I expect to get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Invoice Invoice xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2 
    http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/os-UBL-2.1/xsd/maindoc/UBL-Invoice-2.1.xsd" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xades141="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.4.1#" 
    xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" 
    xmlns:sts="http://www.dianees.com/contra/acturaeca/v1/Structures" 
    xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" 
    xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" 
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2">
    <ext:UBLExtensions>
        <ext:UBLExtension>
            <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
                <cbc:AdditionalAccountID>1</cbc:AdditionalAccountID>
                    <cac:Party>
                        <cac:PartyName>
                            <cbc:Name>GRUPO ERB</cbc:Name>
                        </cac:PartyName>
                        <cac:PhysicalLocation>
                            <cac:Address>
                                <cbc:ID>11001</cbc:ID>
                                <cac:Country>
                                    <cbc:IdentificationCode>CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                                </cac:Country>
                            </cac:Address>
                        </cac:PhysicalLocation>
                </cac:Party>
            </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        </ext:UBLExtension>
    </ext:UBLExtensions>
</Invoice>
```

please show me how to make one and I will do the rest

Comment: what you want can be done but requires a lot of unnecessary coding. I think it is beter to create 2 xml schema definitions, one that matches the raw sql output and the other how you would want it to look. Then use a tool like xsd.exe or xsd2code.exe to generate classes for these files. Compose the sql xml output into the class, create a mapping where you fill the class with the namespaces. and when done serialize it.

Comment: Agree, take a look at xsd2code, might give you an idea on how to solve this from different approuch

Comment: Thanks Martijn , but I dont understand what you mean about create two scheme, I am beginner in this , can you be a llttle more explicit, maybe can you show me an example of how to use xsd.exe, I would apreciate that....

Comment: Hi martijn, I just used xsd.exe and generate a class, this class is very large because I needed to use 7 xsd files. Now how generate a XML from that class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you an idea how to solve your problem. I created a small example. it is far from perfect but is shows in basic which steps to take.

first the no namespace xsd is defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Parent">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Child1" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="Child2" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

then because of the different namespaces in your message i've created the same message with different namespaces. Each namespace is a different file.

Root.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Root" xmlns:p="http://tempuri.org/Parent" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Root" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/Parent" schemaLocation="Parent.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="Root" type="p:ParentType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

parent.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Parent" xmlns:ch="http://tempuri.org/Child" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Parent" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/Child" schemaLocation="Child.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="ParentType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Parent" type="ch:ChildType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Child.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Child1" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Child">
    <xs:complexType name="ChildType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Child1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Child2" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Next step is to create class files using xsd.exe. I use a bat file to execute te commands.

```
@echo off
set exepad=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6.1 Tools\xsd.exe
set sourcepad=..\..\

set xsdpad=%sourcepad%\console\xsd
set Outpad=%sourcepad%\console\generated

Set NameSpace=Console.generated

"%exepad%" "%xsdpad%\NoNSmessage.xsd"  /c  /n:%NameSpace%  /o:%Outpad%

"%exepad%" "%xsdpad%\Child.xsd" "%xsdpad%\Parent.xsd" "%xsdpad%\Root.xsd"  /c  /n:%NameSpace%  /o:%Outpad%

pause
```

Then import the generated class files into your project so they can be used.

this is an example how you can map the fields from the source to the target.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string msg1 = "<Root><Parent><Child1>First</Child1><Child2>Second</Child2></Parent></Root>";

            //deserialize xml string into class object.
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
            var reader = new StringReader(msg1);
            var noNamespaceRoot = (Root)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);

            //map the fields from the nonamespace msg to the msg with a namespace
            var namespaceRoot = new ParentType();

            namespaceRoot.Parent = new ChildType();
            namespaceRoot.Parent.Child1 = noNamespaceRoot.Parent.Child1;
            namespaceRoot.Parent.Child2 = noNamespaceRoot.Parent.Child2;

            //serialize the class object to a string.
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ParentType));
            var sww = new StringWriter();
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, namespaceRoot);
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(sww.ToString());

        }
```

the output will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Root">
    <Parent xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Parent">
        <Child1 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Child">First</Child1>
        <Child2 xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Child">Second</Child2>
    </Parent>
</Root>
```